# (111 connection refused) while connecting to upstream

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php5, php-fpm

I have a ubuntu 13.10 server with nginx and php5-fpm installed, the server has just been started and as such i am sure it is not a buffer or connection overload issue.

I have set the site config in the sites available and created the sym link:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:7777;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

The html pages are accesable and as such this is not an nginx hosting issue, it is a php backend issue.

My www.conf in my php5/fpm/pool.d has 
listen = 127.0.0.1:7777

as required and both php5-fpm and nginx have been restarted.

If I try run any php page on the site {url}/test.php with 
I get the connection refused and 502 browser error

Please can anyone assist me, I have been trying to get this to work for hours now.